# Read a json object in a post call and get value from all the name value pairs

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

JSON parsed to Web API Post Call (Body)

```
{
    "Name1": "Value1",
    "Name2": "Value2",
    "Name3": "Value3",
    "Name4": "Value4"
}
```

Lets call this object NameValueObject

```
 public class NameValueObject
    {
        public Name1 { get; set; }
        public Name2 { get; set; }
        public Name3 { get; set; }
        public Name4 { get; set; }
     }
```

What I would like to see is to be able to parse the json object and convert it into a list

```
public async Task<List<NameValueObject>> EvaluateJson ([FromBody] NameValueObject request)
{
  string serializerequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
  //What do i next , I just to want to get a list of the values sent through the json object

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create  List< NameValueObject >  objects

```
var json= JsonConvert.Serialize(request);

List<NameValueObject> objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json)
.Select(i => new NameValueObject {Name=i.Key, Value=i.Value} )
.ToList();
```

or just list of values

```
var json= JsonConvert.Serialize(request);
                                     
List<string> values=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json)
 .Select(i => i.Value )
.ToList();
```

if you want List< NameValueObject > , you will have to create this class

```
public class NameValueObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

or I would prefer  this

```
public async Task<List<NameValueObject>> EvaluateJson ([FromBody] JObject jsonObject)
{
   return  jsonObject.Properties()
            .Select ( i => new NameValueObject {
             Name =  i.Name, Value = (string) i.Value }).ToList();
}
```

or  just list of values

```
List<string> Values = jsonObject.Properties().Select( i => (string) i.Value ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the values of your properties in the `NameValueObject` by using [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection) and [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) like this:

```
var values = nameValueObject.GetType().GetProperties().Select(v => v.GetValue(nameValueObject));
```

If you would like to get both the name of the property and the value you can create a dictionary like this:

```
var dictionary = nameValueObject.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(v => v.Name, v => v.GetValue(nameValueObject));
```